# Flutter application suddenly has no internet connection at all

Tags: flutter

I am running my application on Android emulator.

I verified the emulator itself has internet connection. I could browse via Google Chrome.
2 months ago everything worked as expected, and I didn't touch the code.
Suddenly, when I run it I have no internet access via the application.

What I did:

1. I verified I have the internet permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in: `android/app/src/[main|debug|profile]/AndroidManifest.xml`.
2. `flutter doctor` - everything is fine.

Any advice? observe? I cannot understand why would I lost the internet connectivity

Comment: Use chrome browser of the emulator to run an Url check whether it's getting response or not?

Comment: @Diwyansh
I don't sure I understand you
I did browse via google chrome

Comment: Yes I just want to make sure that whether is it only your app which is not connecting to the internet or the emulator?

Comment: @Diwyansh
Then yes, I could connect with chrome

Comment: I think you should try updating your app or use Connectivity package to find out whether app getting internet or not.

Comment: @Diwyansh what do you mean by update?
I am using the flutter http package

Comment: By update I mean to update flutter SDK and dependencies as well.

Comment: @Diwyansh
`Flutter is already up to date on channel stable`

Comment: What kind of antivirus software are you using *on your computer*? What happens if you disable it? I've had cases when Kaspersky Antivirus caused such issues.

Comment: Is there any exception in your Run window? How do you know if your application does have access to internet or teh server is throwing exception?

Comment: Do you get a DNS address could not be found -- DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG error (or related) when trying to open a chrome tab? Or how do you noticed that you have no connection?

Comment: @Riwen Indeed. This solved it. Seems like my AV had a foolish software update blocking this emulator connection.

Comment: Glad to hear! I've reposted my answer so that others can learn from it, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting my comment, since it seemed to solve your issue.

In the past, I've faced such errors. In my case, it was caused by the antivirus software (namely, Kaspersky Antivirus) that ran on the host machine. Disabling it temporarily solved the issue entirely. Try disabling any antivirus software and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have shared, it's very difficult to give an exact answer. However you could try to troubleshoot the error. Try below thigs:

1. Create a Webview inside your app and launch to any URL may be `www.youtube.com`
2. Try fetching data from a public REST server API e.g. https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/us/daily.json

If youare able to receive the data from the above 2, then the problem is with your server else you should look into your app code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, please consider adding some additional info.

However, I had a similar problem a while ago, for me it helped to delete the emulator device and simply add a new one. Alternatively, you can try wiping the emulator´s data (`right click > wipe data`).
I don´t know how you verified that the emulator itself has internet connection, but maybe it helps.